# When to use resolvers Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

In which cases do you use resolvers in Angular?
I think it takes a lot of performance, in which case it has optimize using?

Could I reuse resolver and cache it?

Comment: I'd say not much, I did write my thoughts about why not there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49054232/2398593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is somewhat subjective to your use-case but essentially any route change that would benefit from having the data already "resolved" could be considered. I would look at any route change that has a high page load. You should be able to cache the data because resolver is just implemented in a service. That service could cache the data from a state management store example: NgRX or even just a private property in the service itself if you make it a singleton.