# Angular resolver get an Observable

Tags: angular, observable, resolver

I work on Angular 10 project. I get data from my backEnd with a simple

```
return this.http
      .get<{ returned: Animal[] }>('animals')
      .pipe(map((res) => res.returned.map((value) => value)));
```

this is call by my resolver and send through router in my routing module with

```
resolve: {
        animals: AnimalResolver,
}
```

I get resolve data with `this.route.snapshot.data.animals`

I want to have an `Obervable<Animal[]>` for use AsyncPipe. The type return by the resolver is an `Observable<Animal[]>` but I get an error invalid Pipe argument, to resolve this error I need to make :

```
of(this.route.snapshot.data.animals);
```

Why?

Comment: Before you start using resolvers a lot I'd recommend you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054232/why-would-you-use-a-resolver-with-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to use `this.route.data` observable where `route` is [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) while [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) is just "static" data of current route and there are no observables here.

```js
this.animals$ = this.route.data
  .pipe(map(data => data.animals));
```