# Use switchMap operator in a resolver

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to only navigate to the product detail page if the product exists so I created this `productResolver` function

```
export const productResolver: ResolveFn<Product | undefined> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
) => {
  if (isNaN(Number(route.paramMap.get('productId')))) return EMPTY;

  return inject(ProductService)
    .getById(Number(route.paramMap.get('productId')))
    .pipe(filter((product) => !!product));
};
```

And used it in my `products/:id` route

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductComponent,
    resolve: {
      product: productResolver,
    },
  },
])
```

Problem with this implementation is if it takes a while to fetch a product by id. I can still click multiple products in the products list page before the product detail page is rendered and cause issuing multiple HTTP get requests when I only care about the last product that has been clicked

I tried wrapping the `productId` in an observable as follows but it didn't seem to work as expected

```
export const productResolver: ResolveFn<Product | undefined> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
) => {
  const productService = inject(ProductService);
  return of(Number(route.paramMap.get('productId'))).pipe(
    filter((productId) => !!productId),
    switchMap((productId) => productService.getById(productId)),
  );
};
```

Comment: How would a switchmap help here ? Each route change will trigger a new resolver call.

Comment: While switchMap isn't helping here, I'd argue that resolvers are pretty bad IMO for many reasons I've described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054232/why-would-you-use-a-resolver-with-angular I've also mentioned alternatives there that you could use.