# Combine route resolver provider and component provider in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I want to 'attach' a signal store to one of my components. I intend to provide this at component level and not at the root, as the state is specific to that component.

However I like to use route resolvers to prevent navigation to broken pages - in this case I'd not load my component if there was a problem retrieving the data.

Without providing my signal store at root, are there any patterns that can help me share the data between resolver, component and signal store, such that I can get the benefits of both the resolver and the signal store?

Comment: It might work if you provide resolver at the same level to resolve child routes, but if you want to any route be able to resolve data using signal store from some component. i don't think such a pattern exist. I can imagin creating public getter and injecting the component itself, but it is definitely not the thing I'd like to see in my project.

Comment: That's a good point,  If I provided my signal store in my feautre's routes.module then it would be available to my resolver function.  However I anticipate having multiple signalStores for varying componets and I'm not sure I want to provide all of those from my route.module.  Thanks for the suggestion - will see what others suggest whilst I POC that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the route `providers` array. In doing so, the service will be instantiated at the route level.

It'd look like this:

```js
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent,
        providers: [Store],
        resolve: {
          data: (
            route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot
          ) => ({
            storeInstanceNumber: inject(Store).instanceNumber,
          }),
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        component: BComponent,
        providers: [Store],
        resolve: {
          data: (
            route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot
          ) => ({
            storeInstanceNumber: inject(Store).instanceNumber,
          }),
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

And to show you one component, it'd look like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Component A</h1>
    <div>Store instance number: {{ store.instanceNumber }}</div><br />
    <div>Route data: <pre>{{ routeData | async | json }}</pre></div>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class AComponent {
  public readonly store = inject(Store);
  public readonly routeData = inject(ActivatedRoute).data;
}
```

This is just to prove that you can inject the store in both the resolver and the component.

Here's a [live example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3v7klk?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Do note that in doing so, the `Store` provided at the route level is only created **once** per route, on the contrary to once per component instantiation. Depending on what you want, this could either be a feature or an issue: Leaving a route and coming back to it, you'll still have all the data available.

No matter what you want, it's achievable in both cases. Here's an example that'll give a new instance every time we go back to the route `a`, and keep the same Store instance for the route `b`:

```js
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent,
        resolve: {
          store: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) =>
            // small hack to create a new Store instance every time we open that route
            Injector.create({
              providers: [Store],
              parent: inject(Injector),
            }).get(Store),
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        component: BComponent,
        // here we'll get the same Store instance if we leave and come back
        providers: [Store],
        resolve: {
          data: (
            route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot
          ) => ({
            storeInstanceNumber: inject(Store).instanceNumber,
          }),
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

For component B, you don't need to change anything and you can inject the `Store` as usual.

For component A, we need to slightly tweak the code as we now receive the Store instance in the route data:

```js
// this component receives a new Store instance every time it's been created
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Component A</h1>
    <div>Store instance number: {{ store.instanceNumber }}</div><br />
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class AComponent {
  public readonly store:Store = inject(ActivatedRoute).snapshot.data['store']
}
```

Here's [another Stackblitz for this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4jd8fc?file=src%2Fa.component.ts). If you alternate and go to `a`, then `b` a few times, you'll see in the view that the counter on `a` increases but it remains to the same value in `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time. I did not know that we had a providers option against a route, so this is going to help me a lot in future.  This exercise has made me question the appropriateness of route resolvers alongside SignalStore. Their value seems to be in isolating the data retrieval logic, which I've now delegated to SignalStore (with route params from router store). This, combined with the use of dumb/smart components, makes route resolvers a layer that isn't adding much. However I needed to get over the problem that you have solved for me in order to see this. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, that's a very good questioning here. As for resolvers in general to retrieve data, you can read more of what I think about them here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054232/why-would-you-use-a-resolver-with-angular spoiler alert: I'm not a huge fan. They can be useful in some very specific cases, but overall I tend not to use them.